# Is this code using PDO secure?

Tags: php, security, pdo, sql-injection

I am new to PDO. As I heard PDO can prevent SQL injection attack.

Here's what I have written:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.57.36; dbname=somedb; charset=UTF8', 'user1', 'pass1');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($tid));
```

Is it a secure code ? I guess prepared should do some securing acts but the variable is passed to query after it.

Shoud I use addParam before execution method?

Thank you.

Comment: For your secure code question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shoud I use addParam before execution method?

No.

Passing a variable into execute does pretty the same.

There could be other issues though, you can read on them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)